# auto link urls outside of html tag

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink

I have been researching this and only found 2 relevant answers which still didn't work all the way.

anyway. I'm trying to find links in text and autolink them and NOT autolink them if they're already in a html tag. (< a > < img >) and it must support all links like http, https, and www

I'm horrid with regex, but I have tried to put something together.

```
function b($text)
{
   // a more readably-formatted version of the pattern is on http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls
   $pattern  = '(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))';

   $callback = create_function('$matches', '
       $url       = array_shift($matches);
       $url_parts = parse_url($url);

       $text = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
       $text = preg_replace("/^www./", "", $text);

       $last = -(strlen(strrchr($text, "/"))) + 1;
       if ($last < 0) {
           $text = substr($text, 0, $last) . "&hellip;";
       }

       return "<a rel="nofollow" href=".$url.">".$text."</a>";
   ');

   return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $text);
}

function autolink($txt)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('#(?<!href\=[\'"])(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@\#/%()?=~_|$!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@\#/%()=~_|$]#', 'b', $txt);
}
```

but no luck, I have no idea what to do at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a HTML parser of some kind to get this working perfectly. Remember that there are other tags/syntax that can contain URLs, like `<script>`, `<style>`, comments, etc.

If a simple regex solution solving the issues in the question is enough for your case you could use something like:

```
function linkify($input){
    $re = <<<'REGEX'
!
    (
      <\w++
      (?:
        \s++
      | [^"'<>]++
      | "[^"]*+"
      | '[^']*+'
      )*+
      >
    )
    |
    (\b https?://[^\s"'<>]++ )
    |
    (\b www\d*+\.\w++[^\s"'<>]++ )
!xi
REGEX;

    return preg_replace_callback($re, function($m){
        if($m[1]) return $m[1];
        $url = htmlspecialchars($m[2] ? $m[2] : "http://$m[3]");
        $text = htmlspecialchars("$m[2]$m[3]");
        return "<a rel='nofollow' href='$url'>$text</a>";
    },
    $input);
}
```

The first capturing group matches an HTML tag. The expression is replaced with the first capturing group if it's defined (unchanged HTML tag), otherwise with a link to the second or third capturing group.

**[Demo](http://ideone.com/StLoID)**: input:

```
<img src='http://foo'>www.test.com/?x&y
```

Output:

```
<img src='http://foo'><a rel='nofollow' href='http://www.test.com/?x&amp;y'>www.test.com/?x&amp;y</a>
```

Comment: I got unexpected T_SL (>>), I'll try and fix

Comment: I fixed it, I just put it into one line. Thanks again! I really appreciate it as I know nothing of regex haha.

Comment: It's better to replace `$text = htmlspecialchars("$m[2]$m[3]");` to `$text = htmlspecialchars(isset($m[3])? "$m[2]$m[3]" : "$m[2]");`